# BSM audit API on Solaris/UNIX OS

Tags: c, logging, solaris, audit

I am using **Solaris 11.4**, and have the bsm headers, library already set-up, but I cannot find certain functions that are defined in the man page, like **au_fetch_tok** that are mentioned in the [libbsm](https://nxmnpg.lemoda.net/3/libbsm#6) man page.

What I am trying to do here, is to parse the binary audit data and retrieve it in human readable form. (basically a plugin like audit_syslog, etc).

Please let me know why i am missing lot of functions. Is there an updated/different man page? or am i doing something wrong? Any inputs will be helpful regarding ways to create a new plugin like audit_syslog. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The man page you've linked to is for a different implementation - OpenBSM for BSD-based operating systems and is not the documentation for the Solaris libbsm.  The Solaris libbsm is undocumented as of Solaris 11 and not a supported interface for writing code against.  The last version of libbsm for Solaris to be documented was for Solaris 10, and can be found in the "(3BSM)" man pages listed in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5172/index.html.